# How to handle two menus in one react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on application where application have two parts one for public and for admin users. I  completed for public side but now I am am facing issue on admin side because when I render my 2nd menu for admin public side menu is also showing . Could someone please help me how to handle just 2nd menu let suppose if user hit ( /admin/home )  then I need to show 2nd menu if user hit (/home) then I want to show Ist menu.

**Admin Route**

```
  <TopMenu>
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              auth={auth}
              path="/dashboard"
              currentUser={"admin" || null}
              roles={["admin"]}
              component={Dashboard}
            />
          </TopMenu>
```

**Public Route**

```
  <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Home {...props} />} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/about"
          render={(props) => <About {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/contact"
          render={(props) => <Contact {...props} />}
        />
```

Comment: Have you tried conditional rendering inside the render function for a component instead? Each page could be it's own component, which in turn are built up by smaller components. And when you are on the admin page, only render the components you need.

Comment: Would like to see more code. Try to abstract away the details about "admin" and "public" and other details specific to the business of the application. What is the technical problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

create a Private Route file and check if user is authenticated if yes show that component and if not redirect to some other route
You can do it like this or implement your own way

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
export const PrivateRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <div>
          <Component {...props} />
        </div>
      ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )
    )} />
  );


export default PrivateRoute
```

and in the main router file you can import the Private Route and use it like this

```js
import PublicRoute from './routers/PublicRoute';
import Appp from './components/Appp';
import PrivateRoute from './routers/PrivateRoute';
const store = configureStore();
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Switch>
          <PublicRoute path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/yourPrivateRoute" component={yourComponent}/>


        </Switch>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```